# How to remove underline link when hover

Tags: css

When I hover a link it's underline and text-decoration: none; doesn't work because of Bootstrap I think

I tried to use !important and :hover but it doesn't work

```css
header .container #porfolio div a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="container">
    <span id="portfolio">
                <div>
                    <a href="/">PORTFOLIO</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="/">Maskim</a>
                </div>
            </span>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: typo issue `#porfolio` --> `#portfolio` .. and you should not use div inside span

Answer (score -1):

You need to target the hover state.

```
header .container #porfolio div a:hover {
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

In your browser, right click on the link and inspect it with devtools. There you can see how to select the element and then adjust your css.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: I saw your comment on the previous answer so I changed my answer to point you in the right direction.